# Incoming TCP SYNs possibilities

Tags: networking, unix, tcp, tcpip, syn

This might be a general TCP question.

Can I receive TCP `SYN` packet on an `ESTABLISHED` connection OR a connection in `TIME-WAIT` state?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `SYN` received on an `ESTABLISHED` TCP connection should not be happening. It could be a delayed packet, which it would be safe to silently drop.

It is possible to end up with the server in `ESTABLISHED` state and client in `CLOSED` state if the connection is lost and is timed out on the client and not on the server, or if the client is restarted. Attempting to open a new connection in this scenario would cause a `SYN` packet to be received in `ESTABLISHED` state. The desired outcome is that the old connection is closed and a new is opened.

The way this desired outcome is achieved is as follows:

- Client sends a `SYN` to create a new connection.
- Server send an `ACK` for the `ESTABLISHED` connection.
- Client responds to the `ACK` with a `RST` packet causing the `ESTABLISHED` connection to go away.
- Client retransmits `SYN` packet to create a new connection.

A `SYN` packet received in `TIME_WAIT` state can happen after the server has closed the connection, and the client opens a new connection with same port numbers. This will cause a new connection to be opened.

Comment: Awesome. This looks like what I am looking for. I'd go back and try to trace this down in kernel code - just to be sure :-)

Answer (score 0):

Neither...`SYN` is only used when the connection is first set up (the three-way handshake) or when the packet is destroyed.

Basically:

`SYN (I want to start a connection) -> ACK/SYN (OK, I want to start a connection too) -> ACK (acknowledged connection, ready for data)`

Conversation flows with `ACK` packets sent by both hosts indicated they recieved each others packets.

At the end, `FIN` is sent to the server and `TIME_WAIT` is set on the socket. When the server responds with a `FIN` packet, the socket is released.

Comment: Do you mean only when a socket is in LISTEN state?

Comment: `LISTEN` has nothing to do with the flags. A `LISTEN` state is a software state saying "socket is waiting for connections" and tells the OS to wait for packets on the port. A `SYN` from a remote client to the socket gets it started.

Comment: Are you saying the threeway handshake is SYN -> SYN/ACK -> SYN? Because it isn't.

Comment: Sorry, last part is an `ACK`...adjusted.